# set GLSurfaceView to show in a limited space

Tags: java, android, android-studio, opengl-es

I'm working on Android Studio and OpenGL ES.
I have successed in making a triangle appear, but I have no idea how to show it in a limited space(i.e 300dp x 300dp).

```
gLView = new MyGLSurfaceView(this);
setContentView(gLView);
```

I think setContentView(R.activity.something); and setting a GLSurfaceView in the activity (with layout size:300dp x 300dp) should work, but don't know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create layout with surfaceView, for example activity_gl.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        tools:context=".activities.OpenGLActivity">
    <com.app.LimitedSurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/oglView"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"/>
    <!-- other elements -->
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And create LimitedSurfaceView class:

```
package com.app;

public class LimitedSurfaceView extends GLSurfaceView {
    private SceneRenderer renderer;

    public LimitedSurfaceView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public LimitedSurfaceView(Context context, AttributeSet attributes) {
        super(context, attributes);
    }

    public void init(Context context) {
        setPreserveEGLContextOnPause(true);
        setEGLContextClientVersion(2); // or setEGLContextClientVersion(3)
        renderer = new SceneRenderer(context);
        setRenderer(renderer);
        setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY);
        ...
    }
}
```

Then in OpenGLActivity class initialize limitedSurfaceView:

```
package com.app.activities

public class OpenGLActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private LimitedSurfaceView limitedSurfaceView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle state) { 
        super.onCreate(state);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_gl);
        limitedSurfaceView = findViewById(R.id.oglView);
        limitedSurfaceView.init(this.getApplicationContext());
        ...
    } 
}
```

Result:

[image]